# C++: Get Iterator from the pointer to an array of doubles

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I have a pointer to double to which i am allocating n cells. Now I need to access the begin and end iterator objects of this pointer. Here is my code:

*my_module.cpp*

```
# include c_vector.h
/* .. */

C_Vector a(n);
```

*c_vector.h*

```
class C_Vector{

/* .. */
public:
  C_Vector (int n);
  bool Create (int n);
private:
  int n_s;
  double *z;
}
```

*c_vector.cpp*

```
C_Vector::C_Vector(int n) {
   Create(n);
}
bool C_Vector::Create(int n) {

   if ( (z = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double))) != NULL ){
        n_s = n;
   }
}
```

Now in my module file I wish to access a.begin().
How can I do that? Is it possible? 
Please advise.

Avishek

Comment: Don't you mean `z.begin()`?

Comment: you can use *z to get the first element and *(z + n) to get the nth element

Comment: No...My "array" is a!

Comment: @ Kunal: Yes you were right, but I had to define my own begin and end as Mike pointed out.

Comment: "Please advise."  *Don't* use `malloc` and *do* use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So write `begin` and `end` member functions:

```
typedef double * iterator;
iterator begin() {return z;}
iterator end()   {return z + n_s;}
```

It would be polite to provide `const` overloads:

```
typedef double const * const_iterator;
const_iterator begin()  const {return z;}
const_iterator end()    const {return z + n_s;}
const_iterator cbegin() const {return begin();}
const_iterator cend()   const {return end();}
```

Then, once you've learnt how to implement a vector, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I need a Iterator object to use the algorithms.

Comment: @AvishekDutta: Pointers can be used as iterators.

Comment: I was doing vectors..but you know...bosses!

Comment: with reference to your previous comment, I am actually talking about the "algorithm" library, I wanted to use find() or max_element()

Comment: @AvishekDutta: Yes, you can use pointers as iterators in the `<algorithm>` library. Iterators don't have to be class types; they just have to support various operations like dereferencing with `*`, incrementing with `++`, etc., all of which are supported by pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I wouldn't recommend using a pointer here; it's more suitable that you use a contained, dynamically-allocated array like `std::vector`. Besides, raw pointers do not have a `begin` and `end` method:

```
class C_Vector
{
public:
    // ...
private:
    std::vector<double> z;
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: @ 0x499602D2 & Mike: Feel my misery! I am using a open source code base, the types are all defined there and  I have to use their types.